# ActionChains is not updating the data within the table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view/timeseries/CUUR0000SA0) using Selenium.

There are three features in data, "Value", "Net change" and "percent change", including values for net and percentage changes for 1, 3, 6, and 12 months. I want to fetch 1 month's net change and percent change. For that, I need to click on the check boxes and click on the update button.

Now, I performed these actions using selenium's find element by XPath method but for percent change, I needed to use the ActionChains command, as I was getting "Element not clickable error".

When I execute the code, all three features should occur in the downloaded csv. But that's not happening. I am just able to fetch "Value" and "1 Month Net change". If anyone knows, may I know, why the is not getting updated and or how to fix it? Thanks

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view/timeseries/CUUR0000SA0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/fieldset/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label/input').click()  //1 month net change
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '// [@id="percent_monthly_changes_div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label/input')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()   //1 month percent change
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/form/div[4]/input').click()  //update button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="csvclickCU"]').click()   //download csv button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is showing N/A in the column of 1 Month Net change.
if you still not getting 1 month % change value you can do

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#percent_monthly_changes_div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > label > input").click()')
```

instead of:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '// [@id="percent_monthly_changes_div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label/input')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

[image: column of 1 Month Net change]

this might not be the optimal solution, but it works fine.
and 1 month net change value is not given from the website itself.

Comment: ps: when developing you better not use a headless browser, so you can monitor what's happening on the website.

Comment: Thank you so much !! This is really helpful. I was stuck in it for the last three days.

Comment: You are welcome.
I'd suggest to you to change the script to the one suggested by @undetectedSelenium in the answer down below since it's more optimal.

Comment: I tried it but it actually isn't working for me. The feature was not updating.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the elements with text as **1-Month Net Change** and **1-Month % Change** using ***ActionChains*** will be an overhead and you can avoid it easily.

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view/timeseries/CUUR0000SA0")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='1N']"))).click()
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='1P']").click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://beta.bls.gov/dataViewer/view/timeseries/CUUR0000SA0")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='1N']"))).click()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='1P']").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: beta_bls_gov]